# Convert Video in html5 with ffmpeg on aruba

Tags: ffmpeg

How can I convert an uploaded video file in html5 with ffmpeg?

I'm on a Aruba Linux Hosting. If for example I upload a video file in

```
http://www.example.com/upload/video1.mpg
```

I'd like to get:

```
http://www.example.com/upload/video1.m4v (or webm)
```

Excuse me for my English.

Answer (score 1):

If ffmpeg is installed then you should able to convert using ffmpeg on your server.

Logon, change to the directory video1.mpg is located and run:

```
fmpeg -i video1.mpg video.m4v
```